# Android Download manager Can only download HTTP URIs:

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Well I am trying to download file via download manager my url adress starts as:

> https://dl.dropbox.com...

it is working fine on android 4.1.2 or others. but it gives error at android 2.3.3 and this log cat

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP URIs: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jcy3ahcauj7gu...
>
> at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.(DownloadManager.java:440)

Answer (score 1):

**Update Nov. 2019:** You shouldn't have this problem nowadays with minSdkVersion being at least API 19, the native `DownloadManager` should support `https` just fine. This was different in the Android 2.x era.

**Original answer:**

Replacing `https` for `http` in the `URL` is not the solution as it's often suggested. There is **no guarantee** that the same resource is served in plain `http`.

What I found to be the best, is backporting the DownloadManager by adding it to your sources. There are mainly two classes that you will need: [DownloadMananger](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/7f9f99ea11051614a7727dfb9f9578b518e76e3c/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java) & [Downloads](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/7f9f99ea11051614a7727dfb9f9578b518e76e3c/core/java/android/provider/Downloads.java). You will have to do a few changes to the sources, like changing the package name and using DownloadManager's constructor directly instead of using `getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)`.

This way you get the functionality without compromising on older devices. If you want, you may conditionally decide whether to use the native implementation or the one provided in your sources, depending on the version of Android the device is running.

Someone already did this with a slightly older version, check his [github](https://github.com/alvinsj/android-https-downloadmanager-demo).