# Download file using Download manager

Tags: android, http, android-download-manager

I'm trying to download file from dropbox.when I try download this Url **https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf68ylazusvpnga/Cir_IMG-10-20181025145334.jpg?raw=1** ,App is crashing I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf68ylazusvpnga/Cir_IMG-10-20181025145334.jpg?raw=1"
    at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.<init>(DownloadManager.java:436)
    at com.valai.school.adapter.ImageMessageViewHolder.downloadImageFile(ImageMessageViewHolder.java:140)
    at com.valai.school.adapter.ImageMessageViewHolder.access$000(ImageMessageViewHolder.java:43)
    at com.valai.school.adapter.ImageMessageViewHolder$2.onClick(ImageMessageViewHolder.java:124)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(message.getAttachmentURL().trim()));
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, imageFolderPath, fileName);
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423700/download-http-https-uris-with-downloadmanager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147934/android-download-manager-can-only-download-http-uris

Comment: tried not working

Comment: run same code with this link and let me know

Comment: "https://freemusicdownloads.world/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/John-Legend-All-of-Me.mp3"

Comment: Guys i solved that issue.it is url backend problem Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf68ylazusvpnga/Cir_IMG-10- 
20181025145334.jpg?raw=1";
DownloadManager.Request request = new 
DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url.trim()));
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
| DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, "/images", "sample");
final DownloadManager manager = 
(DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
Log.d(SO, " download id " + downloadId);`
```

Working for me.